# How to efficiently run multiple lucene search queries on MemoryIndex document?

Tags: search, memory, indexing, lucene

I am using MemoryIndex in lucene Java API to index a text content in memory and run queries over it. There can be hundreds of such queries running on a single doc to get matches. I would like to know the efficient way to do this.

Currently I am creating multiple Query objects and looping over them to see which match my text in memory.

The text can be few KBs in size.
Queries will be complex boolean and phrases combined.
Size of a query might be around 1KB max.

Comment: do you try just to implement a simple search and measured performance or is this more like a theoretical question in which you may face performance issues?

Comment: This is for perfomring streaming analytics. We will have to match multiple rules against each incoming doc and categorize according to which rules it matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been up for quite some time and I will try to answer it myself.

I implemented this by storing all my parsed query objects in a list. I will frame the query using Query Parser and have this stored in my list in memory. 

It will improve performance as I do not have to keep building my queries every time a new text comes.

In my case, we had hundreds of complex queries but these were static and do not change. Hence, it made sense to have the parsed queries stored in memory and not build them everytime.
I have implemented this more than a year back at my previous company using apache lucene and java. 

**Note: One major problem I faced was with the default stopword filter in lucene which was trimming out some parts of the text and this was not the behaviour I needed.**
I do not have access to the code anymore, sorry if the answer seems very ambiguous.

Useful classes: 
https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_6_2/memory/org/apache/lucene/index/memory/MemoryIndex.html
http://lucene.apache.org/core/6_6_2/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/QueryParserBase.html#parse-java.lang.String-